# JSP how to access class object variables

Tags: html, jsp

I know to access variables passed to a .jsp page, I can use `${serviceRequestData['FN_Contact']}` . My issue is that I am passing an Object, lets say `bike` which has a variable `wheelPressure` , how can i access the `wheelPressure` variable from a .jsp page?

For example, in JAVA I would use something like `bike.getWheelPressure()`

Comment: You should try using ${bike.wheelPressure}

Comment: did not work unfortunately: `.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page `

Comment: Is there anymore to that error message?  I would not expect that ${bike.wheelPressure} could produce that error. It should either work or be ignored by the JSP engine.  You might have to show us your code. If you did, then we could try to reproduce your error.

Comment: @rickz thanks for your interest but I found these syntax needed finally: `${serviceRecordData.getId()}` turns out its almost the exact same as JAVA